# Intensive Query-ing on DB making load time insane

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, performance, algorithm

I am trying to implement a content based recommender for my tweet application which I think I managed to do . The problem is though that my solution is so DB intensive that it makes the load times too long. So I come here for some help . In the following section I will post the algorithm which I will then proceed to explain.

```
def candidates2(user)
     @follower_tweet_string = ""  ## storing all the text from all the tweets from all the followers that a user has
     @rest_of_users_strings ## storing all the text from all the tweets a user, that the current user is not following, has.
     scoreHash = Hash.new ## a score hash where the score between the similarities found by the TfIdSimilarity gem are kept
     @rezultat = [] ## the array of users returned 
     @users = User.all ## all the users
     @rest_of_users = [] ## all the users that the current user is not following
     @following = user.following + Array(user) ## all the user the current user is following + the user

     @following.each do |followee|
        @tweets = followee.feed ## feed is a method for requesting all the tweets of that person
         @tweets.each do |tweet|
           @follower_tweet_string = @follower_tweet_string + tweet.content ## getting all the text from all the tweets of all the followers
         end
     end

     @rest_of_users = @users - @following  ## finding out all the users that the user is not following

     document1 = TfIdfSimilarity::Document.new(@follower_tweet_string)
     corpus = [document1]

     @rest_of_users.each do |person|
      @tweets = person.feed ## getting all the tweets of the user 
      @tweets.each do |tweet|
        @follower_tweet_string = @follower_tweet_string + tweet.content ## getting all the text from all the tweets that a user has(a user that isn't followed by the current user)
      end

      ##calculating the score 
      document2 = TfIdfSimilarity::Document.new(@follower_tweet_string)
      corpus = corpus + Array(document2)

      model = TfIdfSimilarity::TfIdfModel.new(corpus)
      matrix = model.similarity_matrix
      scoreHash[person.email] = matrix[model.document_index(document1), model.document_index(document2)]
      corpus = corpus - Array(document2)
      ## stop calculating the score

     end

     sortedHash = Hash[scoreHash.sort_by{|email, score| score}.reverse[0..4]] ## sorting the hash

     @rest_of_users.each do |rank|
      if sortedHash[rank.email] then
        @rezultat = @rezultat + Array(rank) ## getting the resulting users
      end
    end


    @rezultat ## returning the resulting users
  end
```

The algorithm can be found  [here](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-730/paper3.pdf) on page 6 , chapter 3.2, Content-based-Recommender(20 lines of explaining or so).

The main problem of my algorithm is that I have to take all the users that are not followed and then take all their tweets and then apply the algorithm . This is very very DB intensive, it's insane. I can't do that... Any ideas of how can I improve this ?

Comment: One optimisation strategy is not so much to do with database activity but with **object instantiation**.  If you do `User.all`, and have (eg) a million users, the `select * from users` query might take a couple of seconds, but Rails will then take these results and build a million ActiveRecord objects out of them.  The code to initialize these is complicated and so this will slow you down like crazy.

Comment: I am a newbie... I understand what you are saying but I don't know how to do what you are saying :D  . The select * is ok the feed is actually pretty rough..

Comment: When you say "I have to take all the users that are not followed and then take all their tweets " do you mean "all of the other twitter users"?  There are like a million twitter users, you do not ever want to be getting all of their data.

Comment: no no . I have my own database with like 200 users :D (it's an application that tries to mimic Twitter , well at the core level, I can't code like them =)) )

Comment: And I wanted to implement this recommendation algorithm :D . That requires me to parse all content of all the tweet of some of the recent posting users, since my db is so small I just take them all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should separate generating recommendations from displaying them.

That is, you have a batch processing job that processes tweets, and produces recommendations, then stores them in the database.  This job runs regularly.

Separately you have a web interface that can query the database for current recommendations, and then display them.

Now load time is fast.  Web response time is fast.  And your performance problems now show up as how often you can run the batch processing job.  Which is a context where latency is less of an issue, and is something that is more readily addressed with techniques like running parallel jobs.

Comment: Soooo , i should run a background process that activates from time to time ?

Comment: @LucianTarna Yes.  And how often it runs will affect how up to date your data is.

The next standard optimization is to add an incremental run mode where it takes existing data, then updates it slightly for new recent tweets.  This incremental version will run faster and can be run more often.